# Draw an arc between 2 nodes and label it in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have already drawn two ellipses `l1` and `l2`, `l2` is on the left below `l1`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (l1) [ellipse, draw=black, fill=white!20, text=black, scale=0.8, text centered]{
    $l_1$};
  \node (l2) [ellipse, draw=black, fill=white!20, text=black, scale=0.8, text centered, below left=1cm of l1]{
    $l_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to draw an arc from the south of `l1` to the north of `l2` with a `->`. The aim of drawing arc instead of a line is to make it prettier, so just a little radian will be fine, no need to be very accurate.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Also I would like to label the arc in its middle. The label, which is actually a word, will be ideally displayed horizontally.

Comment: Your code does not compile for me. What TiKZ libraries are you using?

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap: `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,shapes.multipart}`

Comment: Thanks. Generally, you should post a complete working document in such cases, to avoid such confusion. (Especially where TiKZ is involved, which has more accessories than the proverbial Malibu Stacy doll.)

Comment: By the way: `fill=white!20` doesn't make much sense: You're mixing 20% white with 80% white, ending up with white. What would make sense would be `fill=white!20!blue`, which mixes 20% white with 80% blue, or `fill=blue!20`, which mixes 20% blue with 80% white. If you want to get a semi-transparent background, specify `fill=white, opacity=0.2`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can draw the the arc with an arrow tip by using `\draw [bend right,->] (l1) to (l2);`. The curvature can be specified using `bend right=<angle>`.

To add a label, you can add a node halfway along the path by inserting `node [auto] {<text>}` after `to`. The `auto` keyword makes sure that the text doesn't overlap the line. If you want the text on the other side of the line, you can add the keyword `swap` after `auto`. The distance along the path can be controlled using `at start`, `very near start`, `near start` (or the equivalent expressions with `end`), or by specifying a fraction using `at=<pos>`.

Note that you don't need to set `text centered` explicitly, as this is the default behaviour.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (l1) [ellipse, draw=black, fill=white!20, text=black, scale=0.8]{
    $l_1$};
  \node (l2) [ellipse, draw=black, fill=white!20, text=black, scale=0.8, below left=1cm of l1]{
    $l_2$};
\draw[bend left,->]  (l1) to node [auto] {Link} (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just posted antoher related question: [draw a special arc from 1 node to another in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27225/draw-a-special-arc-from-1-node-to-another-in-tikz), could you please take a look if you want?