# Draw a special arc from 1 node to another in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Even though I just learned how to draw an arc, I have difficulties in drawing the arcs in the figure. Especially the arc from the second circle to the first one. If I do: `\draw[bend left,->]  (l2.south) to node [auto] (l1.north)` (where `l1` is the circle above, and `l2` is the circle below), the line will cross the circles and make the picture not pretty.

So does anyone know how to draw the arc from `l2` to `l1`? Another thing is I would like this arc goes from the south of `l2`, and points to the north-west of `l1` (instead of north of `l1`)

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to define a support point for this. You can use the syntax `+(<x>,<y>)`, which specifies a point relative to the starting point. In order to smooth the curve, you'll have to make sure that the `in` value of the path segment going into the support point, and the `out` value of the segment leaving the support point add up to 0. To adjust the path of the curve, you can play with `looseness`, `in looseness` and `out looseness`, which specify how "curvy" the path is.

By specifying an `out` and `in` angle for the first and last segment of the path, you can determine at what location the path leaves or enters a node. Alternatively, you could specify `(<node name>.north west)` to make the path start or end at the top left of a node, or use `(<node name>.<angle>)` to specify at what angle on the shape outline the path will start or end, with `0` pointing due east, `90` due north, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,ellipse}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below left=2cm and 0.5cm of A] (B) {B};
\draw[out=-90,in=90,->]  (A) to  (B);
\draw [->] (B)  to [out=-90,in=-90,in looseness=2.5] +(-1cm,1cm) to [out=90,in=135,out looseness=1.5](A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you're  not set on the path leaving node `B` from the south, but instead make it leave from south west, you can instead just write

```
\draw [->] (B)  to [out=-135,in=135,in looseness=1.5] (A);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your code does not compile, it gives an error `Package tikz Error: ( expected.`...

Comment: @SoftTimur: This works fine for me. Perhaps you are using an older version of the libraries.

Comment: That's weird, it compiles fine for me if I copy the whole code block into a new document. Are you using an old (pre 2.1) version of TikZ? You can check that by putting `\listfiles` in your preamble and checking the list near the end of the `.log` file.