# TikZ - game tree representation with continuum of moves

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, automata

I have been using TikZ to draw game-trees for my game-theory lectures (mostly using the automata package) but I could not figure out how to draw an arc across the edges the leave a given node. When we want to denote that a player has a continuum of actions available at a node, we usually draw an arc across the edge leaving such node. For example see the arc crossing the edges that leave the first node in this picture:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I could try to implement this in TikZ? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here you have a possible solution:

1.- place two `coordinates` over the edges (from TiKZ's manual section Edges From the parent node) and

2.- draw the arc between them. How? look at: [Draw an arc between 2 nodes and label it in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27222/1952)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=2pt}]
\node (root) {}     
   child {node (a1) {} edge from parent coordinate[pos=.45] (a11)}
    child {node (a2) {}}
    child {node (a3) {} edge from parent coordinate[pos=.45] (a31)}
    ;
%\node at (a11) {};
%\node at (a31) {};
\draw[bend right] (a11) to (a31);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]Maybe this could help:

```
% Node styles
\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=white}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm]
% The Tree
\node(0)[solid node,label=above:{$P1$}]{} 
child{node(1)[solid node, white]{}
}
child{[white] node(2)[solid node, yshift=-20]{}  %note that you need to adjust the yshift if you change the sibling distance
child{[black] node[hollow node,label=below:{$(a,b)$}]{} edge from parent node[left]{$C$}}
child{[black] node[hollow node,label=below:{$(c,d)$}]{} edge from parent node[right]{$D$}}
 edge from parent node[black, xshift=0,yshift=-42]{$\alpha$} %note that you need to adjust the yshift if you change the level distance
}
child{node(3)[solid node, white]{}
};
% information set
    \draw[dashed,bend right](1)to(3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

`forest` offers a powerful way to draw trees and the `angles` library provides a `pic` for drawing the angles.

A brief introduction to `forest` and an explanation of how to specify a tree using its bracket syntax is included in [the second part of my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254926/) to a related question.

The specific solution given here defines some styles for drawing the tree which need a little explanation.

The most important is a style `cont` for nodes from which the outcome is given by a continuum rather than a discrete set of possibilities.

```
  cont/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      append={[]},
      prepend={[]},
      afterthought={
        \path (!1) coordinate (1) -- (!c) coordinate (c) -- (!l) coordinate (l)
        let \p1 = ($(c) - (!2)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in pic [draw, angle radius=\n1] {angle=1--c--l};
      },
    },
  }
```

- `before typesetting nodes` just delays execution until a later drawing cycle, while ensuring stuff is set before the nodes are typeset.
- `append` and `prepend` are used to add an empty node on each side of the main child (one before and one after).
- `afterthought` contains TikZ code to be executed later. (I tried the `tikz` key but this lost the label for some reason.)
- The initial `\path` just defines some coordinates relative to the current node: `(!1)` for the first child, `(!l)` for the last and `(!c)` for the current node.

To use this, you just add `cont` to the relevant node.

I've also added `result label` and `calc label` for adding labels along the edges of the tree. Each of these takes a single argument. The first typesets a text label above the edge. The second a maths label below the edge.

[image: finished tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  result label/.style={
    edge label/.wrap value={##1 node [midway, sloped, above, anchor=south] {#1}}
  },
  calc label/.style={
    edge label/.wrap value={##1 node [midway, below, sloped, anchor=north] {$#1$}}
  },
  cont/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      append={[]},
      prepend={[]},
      afterthought={
        \path (!1) coordinate (1) -- (!c) coordinate (c) -- (!l) coordinate (l)
        let \p1 = ($(c) - (!2)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in pic [draw, angle radius=\n1] {angle=1--c--l};
      },
    },
  }
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep+=50pt,
    s sep+=30pt,
    if n children=0{
      align=center,
      if n=1{result label=Fail}{result label=Succeed},
    }{
      draw,
      circle,
      minimum width=2.5pt,
      delay={
        label/.wrap pgfmath arg={right:#1}{content()},
        content=,
      },
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
    },
  },
  /tikz/every label/.style={label distance=20pt}
  [Targets choose deterrence, cont
    [Terrorists decide whom to attack
      [, result label=Attack business, calc label=\pi_B
        [$D(\theta_B) + A$\\$D(\theta_T) + 0$\\$m_B$, calc label=\theta_B
        ]
        [$D(\theta_B) + H$\\$D(\theta_T) + 0$\\$n_B$, calc label=1-\theta_B
        ]
      ]
      [, result label=Attack tourists, calc label={1-\pi_B=\pi_T}
        [$D(\theta_B) + \alpha$\\$D(\theta_T) + A$\\$m_T$, calc label=\theta_T
        ]
        [$D(\theta_B) + h$\\$D(\theta_T) + H$\\$n_T$, calc label=1-\theta_T
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example to use the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package (version 2.0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\cntmApreset{.8}
\istrootcntmA(0)<45>{Targets choose deterrence}+15mm..30mm+
  \istbA \endist
\xtCommentTo[draw=none](0)(.5,.-.1){$D(\theta_B),D(\theta_T)$}[r]
\xtdistance{20mm}{40mm}
\setistmathTF001[textur]
\istroot(1)(0-1)+20mm..70mm+
  \istB{Attack Business}[above,sloped]{$\pi_B$}[br]
  \istB{Attack Tourist}[above,sloped]{$1-\pi_B=\pi_T$}[bl]
  \endist
\xtCommentTo[draw=none](1)(.5,.-.1){Terrorists decide whom to attack}[r]
\istroot(2)(1-1)[chance node]
  \istB{Fail}[above,sloped]{$\theta_B$}[br]
       {\begin{matrix}D(\theta_B)+A\\D(\theta_T)+0\\m_B\end{matrix}}
  \istB{Succeed}[above,sloped]{$1-\theta_B$}[bl]
       {\begin{matrix}D(\theta_B)+H\\D(\theta_T)+0\\n_B\end{matrix}}
  \endist
\istroot(3)(1-2)[chance node]
  \istB{Fail}[above,sloped]{$\theta_T$}[br]
       {\begin{matrix}D(\theta_B)+a\\D(\theta_T)+A\\m_T\end{matrix}}
  \istB{Succeed}[above,sloped]{$1-\theta_T$}[bl]
       {\begin{matrix}D(\theta_B)+h\\D(\theta_T)+H\\n_T\end{matrix}}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```