# Set endpoint of arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\tikzset{
myshape/.style={
  rectangle split,
  minimum height=1.5cm,
  rectangle split horizontal,
  rectangle split parts=2, 
  draw,
  text width=2cm,
  anchor=center,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.2,bend angle = 35, inner sep=2mm,
queue/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split draw splits = false,rectangle split part fill = {white!100,####1} , rectangle split parts=2, draw, anchor=center, minimum height = 1cm},
dispatcher/.style={rectangle,draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!20!white,thick, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1.5cm}]
\node[dispatcher] (disp) {};
\node[queue = gray!50] (queue2) [above right= 0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
\node[queue = red!50] (queue1) [above=0.3cm of queue2] {$\qquad\qquad \qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad$}
edge [pre, bend right,line width = 0.4mm] (disp.east)
;
\node[queue = green!50] (queue3) [below right=0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad$} 
edge [pre, bend left,line width = 0.4mm] (disp.east);
\node[queue = red!50] (queue4) [below=0.3cm of queue3] {$\qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$} 
edge [pre, bend left, line width = 0.4mm] (disp.east);
\draw[loosely dotted, line width = 0.4mm] (queue2) -- (queue3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following picture:

[image: picture]

I was wondering what I should change to do the following:

- Put some text on top of the arrows.
- Let the arrows end at the west side of the queues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify explicitly the begin and end of the arrows. An easy way to connect these arrows is using `edge` and text is added by using `node[above,pos=.9]{text}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\tikzset{
    myshape/.style={
        rectangle split,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2, 
        draw,
        text width=2cm,
        anchor=center,
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.2,bend angle = 35, inner sep=2mm,
    queue/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split draw splits = false,rectangle split part fill = {white!100,#1} , rectangle split parts=2, draw, anchor=center, minimum height = 1cm},
    dispatcher/.style={rectangle,draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!20!white,thick, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1.5cm}]
    \node[dispatcher] (disp) {};
    \node[queue = gray!50] (queue2) [above right= 0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
    \node[queue = red!50] (queue1) [above=0.3cm of queue2] {$\qquad\qquad\qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad$};
    \node[queue = green!50] (queue3) [below right=0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$\nodepart{two}$\qquad$};
    \node[queue = red!50] (queue4) [below=0.3cm of queue3] {$\qquad$\nodepart{two}$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$};
    \draw[loosely dotted, line width = 0.4mm] (queue2) -- (queue3);
    \path (disp.east) edge [->, bend right,line width = 0.4mm]node[above,pos=.85]{text3} (queue3.west)
                      edge [->, bend right,line width = 0.4mm]node[above,pos=.9]{text4} (queue4.west)
                      edge [->, bend left,line width = 0.4mm]node[above,pos=.9]{text1} (queue1.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you also made the code much more readable!

Answer (score 7):

I could not get your code compiling until I replaced `####1` by `#1` in line 19. If you have more complicated annotations, you may find it more convenient to replace the loop by explicit commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\tikzset{
myshape/.style={
  rectangle split,
  minimum height=1.5cm,
  rectangle split horizontal,
  rectangle split parts=2, 
  draw,
  text width=2cm,
  anchor=center,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.2,bend angle = 35, inner sep=2mm,
queue/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split draw splits = false,rectangle split part fill = {white!100,#1} , rectangle split parts=2, draw, anchor=center, minimum height = 1cm},
dispatcher/.style={rectangle,draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!20!white,thick, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1.5cm}]
\node[dispatcher] (disp) {};
\node[queue = gray!50] (queue2) [above right= 0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
\node[queue = red!50] (queue1) [above=0.3cm of queue2] {$\qquad\qquad \qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad$}(disp.east);
\node[queue = green!50] (queue3) [below right=0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad$} (disp.east);
\node[queue = red!50] (queue4) [below=0.3cm of queue3] {$\qquad$  \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$} (disp.east);
\draw[loosely dotted, line width = 0.4mm] (queue2) -- (queue3);
\foreach \a in {1,...,4}
{\draw[ultra thick, in=180,out=50-\a*20,thick,->] (disp.east) to
node[midway,above] {\a}
(queue\a.west);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also really like the curvature you gave the arrows!
I use the ####1 because I am actually working on a beamer presentation and if I use #1 it gives me some error.

Comment: @HolyMonk I'd propose to make your MWE compilable by either using `#1` or by using the beamer class.

Answer (score 5):

slightly modification of nice [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer. adopted to beamer document class, with simplified arrows, use of `chains` and `quotes` library. All not used `tikz` libraries and style definition are removed to obtain mwe (minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, quotes, positioning, shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{scheduler/.style = {
node distance = 3mm and 33mm,
  start chain = A going below,
 queue/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2,
                rectangle split draw splits=false,
                rectangle split part fill={white!100,##1},
                draw, minimum height = 1cm,
                on chain=A},
dispatcher/.style = {rectangle, draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20!white, thick,
                minimum height=1cm, minimum width = 1.5cm},
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto, anchor=south east, sloped, pos=0.9}
                    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Scheduler}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scheduler]
\node[queue=gray]   {$\qquad$
                     \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
\node[queue=red]    {$\qquad\qquad \qquad$
                     \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad$};
\node[queue=green,below=16mm of A-2]
                    {$\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad$
                     \nodepart{two}$\qquad$};
\node[queue=red!50] {$\qquad$
                     \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
%
\node[dispatcher,below left=of A-2] (disp)  {};
%
\draw[loosely dotted, line width=0.4mm,
      shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (A-2) -- (A-3);
\path[thick,-Stealth]
        (disp.east) edge ["text 1"]  (A-1.west)
        (disp.east) edge ["text 2"]  (A-2.west)
        (disp.east) edge ["text 3"]  (A-3.west)
        (disp.east) edge ["text 4"]  (A-4.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess it would be the easiest way to first define your nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
...  
\node[dispatcher] (disp) {};
\node[queue = gray!50] (queue2) [above right= 0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad$ \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
\node[queue = red!50] (queue1) [above=0.3cm of queue2] {$\qquad\qquad \qquad$ \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad$};
\node[queue = green!50] (queue3) [below right=0.1cm and 3cm of disp] {$\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad$ \nodepart{two}$\qquad$};  
\node[queue = red!50] (queue4) [below=0.3cm of queue3] {$\qquad$ \nodepart{two}$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$};
```

And second draw arrows and label them:

```
\draw[<-, bend right, line width = 0.4mm] (queue1) -- (disp) node [auto] {your text};  
\draw[<-, bend left, line width = 0.4mm] (queue3) -- (disp) node [auto] {your text};  
\draw[<-, bend left, line width = 0.4mm] (queue4) -- (disp) node [auto] {your text};  
\draw[loosely dotted, line width = 0.4mm] (queue2) -- (queue3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27222/draw-an-arc-between-2-nodes-and-label-it-in-tikz) might be of help regarding your questions.

I don't know if you know the [TikZ & PGF Manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)? This manual might be a bit overwhelming at first, but I think it is very useful.
Take a look at chapters 3.10 and 3.12 they should be of help regarding your questions too. :-)

Comment: I read the introductory tutorial, so I did read this part, but I guess not good enough! Thank you.